# How to find the nth root of a value?

Tags: swift

In Swift, what would the easiest way to find the nth root of a value be?

Comment: nth root of x is equal to x^(1/n). Does that help?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

We know that the Nth root of a number, x, is equivalent of raising x to a power that is the reciprocal of N.  Knowing this, we can use the `pow` function to find the Nth root:

```
let nthRoot = pow(base, (1/n))
```

where `base` and `n` are floating point variables.

Comment: @Grimxn `1` is a DoubleLiteralConvertible and works just fine.  Please try it yourself.

Comment: apologies. I got very used to writing doubles explicitly, and hadn't noticed that!

Comment: @Grimxn it's important where the type is being implicitly inferred: `let val = 1` creates an `Int` versus `let val = 1.0` creates a `Double`.  But `let val: Double = 1` works perfectly fine.

Comment: @nhgrif I believe this does not work (any more?). The signature of `pow` in Swift 4 is `func pow(_ x: Decimal, _ y: Int) -> Decimal` so `1/n` cannot be a float.

Comment: I stand corrected. 'pow' is overloaded for other data types including `Double`. Although I did not find this in the documentation but here on SO :)

Answer (score 6):

```
    let nthRoot = pow(base, (1/n)) // will return nan for negative base
```

This expression is a partial solution, because it will not work for negative `base` numbers.

Ex. The cubic root to `-27` is well defined(`-3`) by all math laws.

Here is a function that calculates the nth-root properly for negative values, where `value` is the number which will be rooted by `n`:

```
    func nthroot(value: Double, _ n: Double) -> Double {
        var res: Double
        if (value < 0 && abs(n % 2) == 1) {
            res = -pow(-value, 1/n)
        } else {
            res = pow(value, 1/n)
        }
        return res
    }

    nthroot(-27, 3) // returns -3
```

And the same function using ternary operator:

```
    func nthroot(value: Double, _ n: Double) -> Double {
        return value < 0 && abs(n % 2) == 1 ? -pow(-value, 1/n) : pow(value, 1/n)
    }

    nthroot(-27, 3) // also returns -3
```