# How to calculate the 6th root of 2 in Swift?

Tags: swift, foundation, square-root

I am trying to calculate the 6th root of 2 in Swift and I cannot find a suitable function in for this.

There has been one post here titled "[How to find the nth root of a value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30203542/how-to-find-the-nth-root-of-a-value)" where the proposed solution was to use

```
pow(2, (1/6))
```

But I believe this does not work, as the signature for `pow` is

```
func pow(_ x: Decimal, _ y: Int) -> Decimal
```

so the result of the above formula is 1 instead of 1.122462... as `(1/6)` gets rounded to `0`.

The iPhone calculator can do it, so there must be way :)

Thanks!

Comment: You missed the *"... where base and n are floating point variables"* from the referenced answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To compute the 6th root of 2:

```
pow(2.0, 1.0/6.0)
```

You just need to use `Double`s.

There are multiple versions of `pow` for different data types.  By using the floating point literals, Swift will infer them be of type `Double` and select `pow` with this signature:

```
func pow(_: Double, _: Double) -> Double
```

Or you can use logarithms (nth root of x is `exp(log(x)/n)` where `x` and `n` are `Double`s:

```
exp(log(2.0) / 6.0)
```

Comment: Great, thanks! Does this mean the documentation at https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/1779833-pow is wrong?

Comment: No.  The documentation isn't wrong.  `pow` is overloaded with several versions for different data types.

Comment: Ah, good to know. It the overloading documented anywhere? I try to read up on things first but I guess I failed here.

Comment: I'm not sure you failed here.  I think the documentation is just lacking.  Once you implement the right thing, command-clicking on `pow` will take you to the signature in Darwin.C.math, but that doesn't help you ahead of time.  But once you're there, you can see what other functions are defined in Darwin.